# Highlighting the certain words in a word document with python

Tags: python, regex, docx

I would like to highlight all the given words in a given word document, however, I can only highlight the first word in a sentence...

Example: Let's assume that I have the following words in a word document, and I would like to highlight the following words: Approximate Pending May. While it works fine in the first four lines, on the fifth line I can only highlight the "Pending"

```
Approximate 
Pending spending 
May
May
Pending Approximate xx sit May
```

Here is my code, could you please help me out with this?

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR_INDEX
import pandas as pd
import os
import re


path = r"C:\\Users\\files\\"
input_file =  r"C:\\Users\\files\\\Dictionary.xlsx"


# List of words
df = pd.read_excel(input_file) 
my_list = df['dictionary'].tolist()
list_2 = [dic.capitalize() for dic in my_list]
list_3 = [dic.lower() for dic in my_list]
my_list.extend(list_2)
my_list.extend(list_3)


for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".docx"):
        file = "C:\\Users\\files\\" + filename
        print(file)
        doc = Document(file)
        for para in doc.paragraphs:
            for phrase in my_list:
                #start = para.text.find(phrase)
                x = para.text
                starts = re.findall('\\b' + phrase + '\\b', x)
                #print(start)
                if len(starts)>0:
                    #print(starts)
                    #if start > -1 :
                    start = para.text.find(phrase)
                    pre = para.text[:start]
                    post = para.text[start+len(phrase):]
                    para.text = pre
                    para.add_run(phrase)
                    para.runs[1].font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW
                    para.add_run(post)
          
        doc.save( file )
```

Comment: not because of the case sensitivity, but let me edit question to avoid confusion

Comment: Could you please post the solurtion?

Comment: Not sure I get it...

Comment: I was wrong, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem.

Here you insert *pure* text without any formatting into the paragraph which overrides any formatting done previously in the `pre` part:

```
pre = para.text[:start]
...
para.text = pre
```

And here happens the same for the `post` part:

```
post = para.text[start + len(phrase):]
...
para.add_run(post)
```

It always overrides any highlighting done in the previous iteration with *pure* text. The `text` property of `paragraph` gives you only a `string` without the formatting. And from the [documentation of the `text` property of the `paragraph` object](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html):

> Assigning text to this property causes all existing paragraph content to be replaced with a single run containing the assigned text ... Paragraph-level formatting, such as style, is preserved. *All run-level formatting, such as bold or italic, is removed*.

You can see this if you change the order of the elements in `my_list`. Only the last element will be highlighted. I started with

```
my_list = ['approximate', 'may', 'pending']
```

and the result was a highlighted `Pending`. Then I switched to

```
my_list = ['approximate', 'pending', 'may']
```

and the result was a highlighted `May`. I'm referring here to the last line in your example.

**EDIT**: Here’s an attempt to fix it.

I’ve replaced

```
# List of words
df = pd.read_excel(input_file) 
my_list = df['dictionary'].tolist()
list_2 = [dic.capitalize() for dic in my_list]
list_3 = [dic.lower() for dic in my_list]
my_list.extend(list_2)
my_list.extend(list_3)
```

with

```
# List of words
df = pd.read_excel(input_file) 
my_list = df['dictionary'].tolist()

# Setup regex
patterns = [r'\b' + word + r'\b' for word in my_list]
re_highlight = re.compile('(' + '|'.join(p for p in patterns) + ')+',
                          re.IGNORECASE)
```

and

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".docx"):
        file = "C:\\Users\\files\\" + filename
        print(file)
        doc = Document(file)
        for para in doc.paragraphs:
            for phrase in my_list:
                #start = para.text.find(phrase)
                x = para.text
                starts = re.findall('\\b' + phrase + '\\b', x)
                #print(start)
                if len(starts)>0:
                    #print(starts)
                    #if start > -1 :
                    start = para.text.find(phrase)
                    pre = para.text[:start]
                    post = para.text[start+len(phrase):]
                    para.text = pre
                    para.add_run(phrase)
                    para.runs[1].font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW
                    para.add_run(post)
          
        doc.save( file )
```

with

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".docx"):
        file = "C:\\Users\\files\\" + filename
        print(file)
        doc = Document(file)
        for para in doc.paragraphs:
            text = para.text
            if len(re_highlight.findall(text)) > 0:
                matches = re_highlight.finditer(text)
                para.text = ''
                p3 = 0
                for match in matches:
                    p1 = p3
                    p2, p3 = match.span()
                    para.add_run(text[p1:p2])
                    run = para.add_run(text[p2:p3])
                    run.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW
                para.add_run(text[p3:])
        doc.save(file)
```

It worked for the sample you provided. But I’m not a regex-wiz, there might be a conciser solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think it works with the given example. let me please try with the real files