# Assigning a colour code to a word in docx and replacing

Tags: python, replace, docx, highlight

Hi I would like to know how do I assign a colour code to each item in a generated list of words? Currently stuck on WD_COLOR_INDEX which doesn’t allow me to loop efficiently through the items in the list. Is there any other function I can use? Eventually I would like to do a replacement function for example:

Replacing ‘app’ (highlighted in pink) with ‘apple’ (highlighted in green), hence replace all words highlighted in pink with green. Though I can do a simple word replacement, the highlight allows me to locate the word in the word document.

Appreciate any help I can get, thanks!

This is what I’ve tried and it works for me, except it’s in a single colour only: [Highlighting the certain words in a word document with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146833/highlighting-the-certain-words-in-a-word-document-with-python)

Comment: use jinja can do this, just make a docx template and then use your list to render it

Answer (score 0):

```py
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR_INDEX

def highlight_words(document, word_list):
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        for word in word_list:
            if word in paragraph.text:
                run = paragraph.runs
                i = 0
                while i < len(run):
                    if word in run[i].text:
                        run[i].font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW  # Set highlight color to yellow
                        run[i].text = run[i].text.replace(word, f'[{word}]')  # Enclose the word in square brackets to mark it
                    i += 1

# Create a new Word document object
doc = Document()

# Generate a list of words
word_list = ['app', 'banana', 'orange']

# Insert some paragraphs and words into the document
doc.add_paragraph('This is an app')
doc.add_paragraph('I like to eat banana')
doc.add_paragraph('I have an orange')

# Call the function to set the highlight color and replacement mark for words
highlight_words(doc, word_list)

# Save the document
doc.save('highlighted.docx')
```

In this example, we use the `highlight_words()` function to iterate through the paragraphs of the document and check if each paragraph contains any of the words to be highlighted. If a match is found, we use the `run.font.highlight_color` property to set the highlight color of the word and then use the `run.text.replace()` function to replace the word with a mark enclosed in square brackets. Finally, we save the document and get a Word document with highlighted words.

You can customize the color codes according to your needs and set different colors and replacement functionality using appropriate conditions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for contributing! Is it possible to soft code it in such a way that instead of using words like app and example, colour codes assigned to the word are used instead? I also would like to randomise the colour generated to different words and see the output of the colour code to each word instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @sevenlemon I have made the modifications. You can come and have a look.